# Outlook 2016 / Other folder / read

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook introduce the "Other" folder which moves messages automatically to that folder.  This move is not done through rules, but I would like those messages to NOT be included in the "Unread" category.  As they are "non-important" I would rather they also be marked as read, and be removed from the unread count.  Better yet, leave them as unread, but keep the UnRead count scoped to only those items in the "Focused" folder.

Is there a way to configure this? I don't like creating a rule as 1) it often does not work, and 2) it's client side, and 3) I use a variety of devices and I would like this occur on the Exchange/Server side.

Answer (score 0):

The option is available to Outlook for Mac, see [Focused Inbox for Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/focused-inbox-for-outlook-f445ad7f-02f4-4294-a82e-71d8964e3978#bkmk_outlmac):

*Tip: You can set the badge count—the count of unread mail—to include only the messages in the Focused list. See Outlook > Preferences > Notifications and Sounds > Badge count to adjust this setting.*

But for Windows, I am afraid there is no way to configure this. You may vote for the post in Outlook uservoice forum to submit the feedback:

[Disable Inbox Unread Email Count for Other in Focused Inbox in Outlook 2016](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/19523959-disable-inbox-unread-email-count-for-other-in-focu)